# How to map the CSV file with MySQL column name?

Tags: mysql, csv

I'm a newbie to MySQL
Ex: 
If MySQL table has 20 columns and I want to upload a CSV file which contain 10 columns, how to map CSV columns with MySQL columns so that the values insert into respective fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Query like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
  INTO TABLE t1
  (@var1, @var2)
  SET column7  = @var1,
      column13 = @var2;
```

Comment: the answer u have given it can be done statically. but his question describe it to be done dynamically. ie user should get privalages to select the column using some drop box and match it to csv column